# Running gradlew cAT with in jenkins shell fails with com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices

Tags: jenkins, android-gradle-plugin, automated-tests

I am running gradlew cAT command via jenkins but it fails with Error:
com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!

If I run adb devices command the device is listed properly

- I have connected the android device to the Master Node
- I am running gradlew cAT command and getting below error.

> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only difference I can see is the user under which you are running the gradlew command.
Try Switching to root and try. Sometime Jenkins user can give problems.